# My python script when executed prints values to a single column of the excel document in which it is opened

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I've been attempting to copy over lines from a csv(comma delimited) to another csv file after performing a simple check. But, the newly created output happens to be in a single column. How can I fix this? I've already attempted to migrate over values using the text solution in excel with no positive results. What I provided in the block quotes is one sample csv input that would be in ~400mb file that would need to be read for the given condition before being copied if the condition is met to the second file.

> "Glyma0022s00420.1,1932,1932,1,5.397348971,9.108346736,13.06778834,13.60298787,0.77651741,0.117442453,11.76078538,8.366009655,10.94107876,12.25047115,0.985502816,0.938466273,11.36138317,9.161105262,15.77093455,14.41819843,0.727405702,0.019170303,12.43972822,16.69100507,0.714607056,0.403279462,""osi,rcom,"",gi|225423945|ref|XP_002279093.1| PREDICTED: hypothetical protein [Vitisvinifera],No hit,""tr|B9ST04|B9ST04_RICCO DNA binding protein,>putative OS=Ricinus communisGN=RCOM_0353100 PE=4 SV=1"",""PF01426,PF05641"",None,None,None,None,AT1G68580.1,None,agenet domain-containing protein / bromo-adjacent homology (BAH) domain-containing protein,PF01426|PF05641 BAH domain|Agenet domain

This would be sample input

```
#!/usr/bin/env 

import csv
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv

def pvalueselection(file_in, file_out):
    header = True
    for line in file_in:
        line_split = line.split(',')
        if(header):
            file_out.writerow([line])
            header = False
            continue
        else:
            if float(line_split[9]) <=0.05 or float(line_split[15])<=0.05 or float(line_split[21]) <=0.05 or float(line_split[25])<=0.05:
                file_out.writerow([line])

def main():
    file_in = open(filename, 'rb')

    file_out = open ("output.csv",'wb') 
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out,dialect='excel',delimiter=',')

    pvalueselection(file_in,csv_out)

    file_in.close()
    file_out.close()        

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: `line.split(',')` will return a list just use that to write to csv for example `file_out.writerow(line_split)`. `file_out.writerow([line])`  will not make the line read from file to a list which the writerow method needs rather it would crate a list with only one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_out.writerow([line])` will create a list with only one element 
for example

```
In [1]: test = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
In [2]: list_test = [test]
Out[2]: ['1,2,3,4,5,6,7']
In [6]: len(list_test)
Out[6]: 1
```

what you need is a list of the delimiter separated elements. Use the list after `line.split(",")` in your code would return such list, using the split will solve the problem, for example in the following code

```
In [1]: test = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
In [2]: list_test = test.split(",")
In [3]: print list_test
out:   ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

#now use the writerow method to write the list
file_out.writerow(list_test)
```

The reference documentation has more examples about the usage
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.
Why do you say that it opens in only one column?
This might be your default delimiter in excel (I guess by default is a space/tab).

Open the csv in excel and go to Data->Text To Columns, select 'comma' as delimiter and press finish.

The code seems to be fine.

you can try to change to:

```
 csv_out = csv.writer(file_out,dialect='excel',delimiter='\t')
```

or other delimiter, e.g. ';'